# Disabling UAC on a work computer, at least the audio notifications

Tags: windows-10, audio, uac, notifications

I have work laptop which is set to highest UAC notification setting. It is extremely annoying, especially the bleeboops when I try to launch the task manager. I am able to set UAC to never notify, but after about 10 minutes, it resets to highest notification setting.

Is there any workaround for this? For example can I have a bat file that lowers this every 5 minutes? At the very least can I make the UAC prompts silent (without disabling all system sounds, sometimes it is useful)

Comment: Since this setting is apparently set by group policy: Have you tried talking to your IT department and asking them to change this setting for your laptop? Being a (part-time) sysadmin myself, I'd happily modify our IT security policy if there is a good reason for it (and "being annoying while not effectively increasing security" *is* a good reason), but I'd be mad if I found out that someone tried to work around my security measures without talking to me first.

Comment: As a sound-sensitive introvert,  I simply turned ALL system sounds to "mute" .  This gets rid of notification bleeps from any source but does not interfere with sound from Teams/Zoom/etc meetings, or from web-page videos.

Comment: @Heinzi Afaics UAC on the highest level actually is a security boundary (contrary to all other levels..) so that's probably the reason why they set it to that. Personally I turn off all the system sounds for the same reason too.

Comment: Use a normal account instead of an administrator account, if you use an admin account, most windows program assume you want to open them as administrator, using a normal account gets rid of most popups

Comment: @Voo: Would you like to put it to the test?

Comment: @Joshua Put what exactly to the test and how? A normal user account with uac at the highest level should avoid the usual ways on how to circumvent uac, but I'm always curious to learn new things and I always have a VM to test things.

Comment: @Voo: If your user account has admin access on two machines, limited tokens can spawn elevated processes by accessing the machines over \\machine\c$ shares. No UAC demand is ever generated. (Note that these paths don't work when accessing the same machine so you really do have to have two.) Otherwise, the solution is to set a trap in the registry (event viewer is a common bait program) and wait for the next legit elevation.

Comment: Link for event viewer bait: https://enigma0x3.net/2016/08/15/fileless-uac-bypass-using-eventvwr-exe-and-registry-hijacking/ Article says it's mitigated setting always update, which is true, unless you're willing to wait for the user to eventually start event viewer (which they may or may not).

Comment: @Voo: You're right these work if it's a UAC limited admin account, not an actual limited account. My point with the event viewer bypass is you could set it up and _wait_ for the user to open event viewer.

Comment: @Joshua Well the link says at the end "This particular technique can be remediated or fixed by setting the UAC level to “Always Notify” so that I don't see working at all. The first one I guess could work if you're using an admin user account instead of a normal account though. So a normal user account and UAC on highest level still seems fine.

Comment: @Joshua I do want to try the starting something via `\\machine\c$` with an admin account though (so start powershell over the share or similar?), I can see why that would work. It's interesting, but then again best practice is using a normal account and then using UAC to use the admin account for the specific behavior. And that seems safe from all I've seen so far.

Comment: @Voo: It involves swapping system binaries with hacked versions followed by using sc to restart services. Now, if you have separate user and admin accounts that's a real security barrier no matter what you set UAC to (even all the way down).

Comment: @Joshua So stopping the service, replacing the system binaries via the share (which then doesn't use the split token) and then restarting them? Interesting that that doesn't cause a UAC prompt even on the highest setting anywhere. And yeah I guess it's true that UAC only makes using separate accounts more convenient but the security boundary are the separate accounts in themselves, that's fair.

Comment: High octane exchange.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Your IT dept may take a dim view of changing when UAC is triggered.

To turn the sound off try
`StartMenu` -> `Search` -> `Change system sounds`. Then in `Program Events` change the sound for `Windows User Account Control`  to `Sounds:` `(None)`.
This entry is the last in the `Windows` group. `(None)` is at the start of the `Sounds:` list.

You can use the left arrow on your keyboard to close each group, and then right arrow to re-open the `Windows` group. Then the End key to go to end of the list, the `Windows User Account Control` entry should be at the end of the list.
[image]

Comment: A solution that I can live with without being.. too bold. Thx.

Comment: I think "may" is being charitable.  I've not seen a corporate IT policy where OP's proposed intervention would not be directly forbidden and quite seriously grounds for termination.